# Navigate back and forth in IntelliJ without using arrow keys

Tags: emacs, editor, intellij

I am an emacs person. In emacs, to navigate forward and backward one character I use ctrl-f and ctrl-b. Using IntelliJ I do not want to use the arrow keys. The arrow keys slow me down significantly. In IntelliJ Ctrl-f and Ctrl-b are already assigned to find and go-to-declaration, respectively.

I am curious to know if and how some of you navigate though code in IntelliJ **without relying on arrow keys.**

Also, in the same arrow-key-free manner, any idea for jumping forward/ backward one word at a time? (replacement for the default ctrl-forward_arrow, ctrl-backward_arrow)

Thanks for sharing your experience.

EDIT: a valid solution to this question would allow for touch-typing, meaning the user would not have to lift his hand while working in the IDE. The answer should also preserve the default IntelliJ keymaps.

Comment: I'm flagging this question as off-topic because it's subjective - it's asking for people's preferences and opinions. This is not allowed, as per the [help/dont-ask] don't ask page: *"avoid asking subjective questions where... every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favourite ______?”
"*

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just don't see how this can be answered by anything other than "My favorite keyboard shortcut is Foo+Bar!" which makes the question off topic here. Just pick a key combination that works for you and use that, I don't really see how we could help you choose among the various possibilities.